# Unable to make bash default shell in freebsd

Tags: bash, shell, freebsd, .bash-profile

I wanted to change my default shell to bash in freebsd. I tried the following:

1.`chsh -s /bin/bash (or /usr/local/bin/bash) <my_username>`

I get this error after entering the password: `chsh: yppasswd_remote(): NIS password update failed`

2.Added `exec /bin/bash --login` to my `.profile` file. But tcsh is still the default shell even after logging out and logging in.

Can you please let me know if anything else needs to be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `/usr/local/bin/bash` (or the path to your bash) is in `/etc/shells`. Chsh only allows changing to a shell on the allowed shell list.

Also, `.profile` is for Bourne shells, not c-shells like tcsh. Your hack should probably have used `.cshrc`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vipw (# man vipw) to edit your passwd file correctly. After run it change your default shell located at end of line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "vipw" tool to edit user's shell.

http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/8/vipw/

You should change user's shell section: /usr/local/bin/bash.
For instance:

```
aokan:*:1002:3024::0:0:User &:/home/pgsql:/usr/local/bin/bash
```

Make sure bash installed:

```
pkg_info |grep bash
```

Answer (score 0):

you can edit your passwd file and in front of your username type the default bash of yours like:

```
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/bin/sh
```

change /bin/sh to where your bash is located.

Comment: Don't ever directly edit that file with anything other than `vipw`.